# .htaccess file extension and $_GET rewrite

Tags: php, file, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i want to rewite these in my .htacces file:

```
/*.php -> /*(/)
```

(e.g. gallery.php to /gallery or /gallery/)

```
/snippets.php*?s= -> /snippets/*
```

(e.g. snippets.php*?s=test to /snippets/test or /snippets/test/)

my code so far:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^snippets/([^/\.]+)/?$ snippets.php?s=$1 [L]
```

the bugs that appear using my code:

/snippets/ and /snippets/test(/) will alert an 500 Error. /snippets works fine.

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Micheal said, you need to change the order, however Michael didn't move the RewriteCond's, which result in the unexpected behavior.

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^snippets/([^/.]+)/?$ snippets.php?s=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```

I verified this code on my test server, just to be sure.

Comment: works like a charm :) except the stylesheet is gone (/snippets/test). on /snippets?s=test it works.. can you say something about that without seeing the code?

Comment: Yep this is right - the `RewriteCond` are bound to the `$1.php` and I forgot to move them along with it. +1

Answer (score 0):

You almost have this correct. To take specific action for `/snippets`, it will need to come before the catch-all rule.  Otherwise the first rule matches and routes to `snippets/test.php` which doesn't exist.

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Match snippets first...
RewriteRule ^snippets/([^/.]+)/?$ snippets.php?s=$1 [L]

# Then the catch-all for remaining matches
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Now its an 403 Error (index.php), an 500 Error on /snippets(/) or /snippets.php and an 404 Error on /snippets/test(/)

Comment: @JonasT. You need to check your error log to find out what the 500 error _actually is_.